# Can I make a Document Library that has a lookup to another list item searchable in that list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-search

If you attach a file in a listitem, that file content is searchable within the list (assuming it has text content).

I wanted to achieve that same but using a separated Document Library related to items in the list in question. Is it possible to make it searchable within the list, any examples of this?

Thank you all.

Comment: I think it is not possible using out of the box capabilities of SharePoint.

Comment: Not even adding a multi lookup to as column to each of the items in the document library?